# XPath: Find a node within a text node

Tags: html, ruby, xml, xpath

I have the following html:

```
<code>The first code block</code>
<p>Some text and <code>the second code block</code> followed by other text</p>
```

I need to find and remove all `code` blocks from it. I use the following XPath `'//code'`, but it finds only the first code block while the second remains.

**Question:** Why `'//code'` is not able to catch the second code block? How to fix it?

**Details:** I'm doing it in Ruby using `Nokagiry`. My code looks like this:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read(htmlFile))
html.search('//code').remove
```

**UPDATE:**

The XPath worked in fact. I just made a mistake in different place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like You forget about iterator...
Try:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read(htmlFile))
html.search('//code').each{|htm| htm.remove}
```

Comment: Thank you. It turns out the the XPath I mentioned in the question worked, I had an error in different place. But your code also works.